# Streaming video in from web camera

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, video-streaming

I wonder how can in load video from a web camera in flash using as3

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

uhm are you looking for [`Video::attachCamera`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/gumbo/langref/flash/media/Video.html#attachCamera%28%29)?

**edit:** sorry, didn't get your question first ... so yeah, there are of course alternatives to FMS ... apart from those mentioned by branden, I think [haxevideo](http://haxevideo.org/) is a very good way to go ... it's small, simple and written in [Haxe](http://haxe.org), which for one is similar to ActionScript and above that is a very cool language you should look into ...

Comment: So according to the livedocs i need a flash media server in order to stream video? Is there another way?

Comment: If you want to stream data from a webcam to somewhere then yes, you need FMS or one of the alternatives (Wowza, Red5(which is open source) or Electroserver are just a few)

Comment: You can't stream client to client?